# How to read an xml file (easy)

Tags: c#, xml, parsing, xml-parsing

I was trying to read xml in C# visual studio but didn't know how to do it very well. First, I tried an if block, like this:

```
if (ReadToNextDescendant("painted_blue"))
{
  // access the coordinates inside and do some work
  // this works
}
```

It worked, and I was able to extract the data from the painted blue coordinates. However, I tried it again for the walls_horizontal and it didn't work. Thus I concluded I need some sort of new function, or perhaps a different approach. However, I'm not savvy in XML parsing. For one thing, I don't understand exactly what ReadToDescendant does and why it didn't work the second time around. Could someone point me in the right direction?

```
<painted_blue>
    (0,0)
    (1,0)
    (1,5)
    (2,2)
</painted_blue>

<walls_horizontal>
    (1,2)
    (1,3)
    (1,4)
    (2,1)
    (2,2)
</walls_horizontal>

<walls_vertical>
    (1,1)
    (1,2)
    (1,3)
    (2,0)
    (2,1)
</walls_vertical>
```

Comment: It looks like `ReadToNextDescendant` is a method in your own class, given that you're not calling it on anything. It would really help if you'd provide a [mcve]. But in general, I'd suggest using LINQ to XML when working with XML. The current structure of your XML is really unfortunate though - it looks like each of those elements should have 5 subelements.

Comment: Look up the XElement class. It is very useful for this sort of thing and is part of what Jon Skeet is referring to when he speaks of LINQ to XML. You should also consider, as Jon Skeet says, fixing your XML so that those coordinates are subelements with, perhaps, x and y attributes.

Comment: Worth noting, and adding: Your XML is not valid XML.

Answer (score 1):

If you can I would really suggest changing the XML format to something like this:

```
<walls_horizontal>
    <coord x="1" y="2" />
    <coord x="1" y="3" />
    <coord x="1" y="4" />
</walls_horizontal>
```

Having nodes for the co-ordinates will make is much easier to manage.

Here is some code

```
public static XmlReaderSettings ReaderSettings()
{
    XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
    settings.CloseInput = true;
    settings.IgnoreComments = true;
    settings.IgnoreProcessingInstructions = true;
    settings.IgnoreWhitespace = true;
    return settings;
}
```

... where ever you read in the file

```
    Stream stream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open);

    var reader = XmlReader.Create(stream, XmlHelper.ReaderSettings());



    if (!reader.IsEmptyElement)
            {
                string tagName = reader.Name;

                while (reader.Read() && !(reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.EndElement))
                {
                    if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
                    {
                        switch (reader.Name)
                        {
                            case "wall_horizontal":
                                var coord = new Coord(reader);
                                break;

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

In a custom coordinate class do something like:

```
public Coord(XmlReader reader)
    {
        if (reader == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("reader");

        if (!reader.IsEmptyElement)
        {
            string tagName = reader.Name;

            while (reader.Read() && !(reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.EndElement && reader.Name == "coord"))
            {
                if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
                {
                    switch (reader.Name)
                    {
                        case "coord":
                            var x = reader.GetAttribute("x");
                            var y = reader.GetAttribute("y");
                            break;
                    }
                }

        }
        }
    }
```

Then do something with your x and y values. This code is boiler plate for what I use. The code may need some tinkering to work with your situation. I hope it points you in the right direction!